# How do you prevent a CheckBox or ToggleButtonBase from changing?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I have a Spark CheckBox and I'm trying to prevent it from changing when clicked. In most Flex components there is a CHANGING event and you can prevent default. I've only found a CHANGE event and if I listen for that event and then set checkbox.selected = !checkbox.selected; it just dispatches changed again and the check box is reselected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just disable any mouse events for this checkbox and would still be able to change the selection programmatically with selected=true:

```
<s:CheckBox id="myCheckbox"
            mouseChildren="false"
            mouseEnabled="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added an event listener for a mouse click event and this seems to work but there is a flicker where you can see it was selected for an instant.

```
IEventDispatcher(checkbox).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:Event):void {
        trace("click");
        ToggleButtonBase(target).selected = !ToggleButtonBase(target).selected;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Using this, if I trace the events, it's:

- change
- change
- click

Not ideal but it seems to be working.